# Is it possible to customize the HTML generated for a django.forms.Form?

Tags: html, django

**Goal**: The first `Form` in my formwizard `WizardView` is passed an initial value which will change what fields are displayed in the generated HTML.

Can I modify the output (perhaps via a custom template) with the help of jQuery to hide certain fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the form using javascript by including the javascript files in your forms 'Media' inner class

```
class MyForm(form.ModelForm):
    ...

    class Media:
        # Paths relative to STATIC_URL
        js = ("js/file.js", "js/file2.js",)
```

But, in my opinion that can be a bit hacky

**Alternatively**, to change a specific field's HTML you should create your own widget for the specific fields you want to edit:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

**Finally**, if you need to dynamically add or remove fields, I think the best way you can do so is in your forms **init** function:

```
class MyForm(form.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.fields['example_field_name'].initial == "some_value":
            # do something ...
```

Comment: If you want JavaScript to control which fields are displayed and hidden, your custom Django form widget can add a class to the HTML output indicating whether the field is initially hidden or displayed. Then your JavaScript switches this class when you want to show/hide the widget.

Comment: Good point, a bit of a mix of the above is probably what is needed

Comment: Yeah, it all depends what the OP specifically trying to do, which isn’t described in much detail in the question. It’s definitely best to start with HTML, and move on from there if necessary.

Comment: I tried adding a inner Media class but it is not rendering out the JS to the HTML. I have added {{form.media}} to my template.